# Troubles starting ASP.NET Core api

Tags: asp.net-core

When I start my webAPI project in VS 2019 for MAC all works fine but when I start it with VS 2019 for Windows I get this error:
[image: error]

When I see my Dependencies I see this

[image: dependencies]

Any idea Please?

Regards

Comment: Try to run `dotnet restore` and check if that work

Comment: The above info shows that  you didn't install the SDK `2.2.7`? The official link : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

Comment: Eureka I have installed the sdk 2.2.402 and the runtime 2.2.7 and now works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Eureka I have installed the sdk 2.2.402 and the runtime 2.2.7 and now works

[official link](http://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2)

Thanks